# How to loop TreeNode of P:treetable data

Tags: primefaces, treetable

I want to Loop TreeTable object in Java code. Here is by Tree Creation code

```
public TreeNode getTreeData()
{

    lstTestProcessByRelease = testProcessBo.findAllTestProcessByReleaseGroupBy(getTestSuite(), getReleaseByTabName());
    List<TestProcess> lstTestScenario = new ArrayList<TestProcess>();
    int parentCount=0;

    root1 = new DefaultTreeNode(new TestProcess("TestScenario","TestCase",0,0),null);

    for(TestProcess tp : lstTestProcessByRelease)
    {
        parentCount = parentCount + 1;
        ExecutionParentOrderValue.put(parentCount, parentCount);
        TreeNode parent = new DefaultTreeNode(new TestProcess(tp.getTestScenarioName(), tp.getTestScenarioName(), 0, parentCount),root1);
        System.out.println("============"+ tp.getTestScenarioName() +"=================");
        System.out.println("Scenario Name (ROWKEY) :"+ parent.getRowKey());
        lstTestScenario = testProcessBo.findAllTestCasesByTestScenarioName(tp.getTestSuite(), tp.getReleaseName(), tp.getTestScenarioName());

        TreeNode child =null;
        int childCount=0;   
        for(TestProcess tc : lstTestScenario)
        {
            childCount = childCount + 1;
            ExecutionChildOrderValue.put(childCount, childCount);
            child = new DefaultTreeNode(new TestProcess(tc.getTestScenarioName(), tc.getTestCaseName(), childCount, parentCount),parent);
            System.out.println("TestCase (ROWKEY) :"+ child.getRowKey());
            System.out.println("Scenario Name :" + tc.getTestScenarioName());
            System.out.println("TestCases Name : " + tc.getTestCaseName());
            System.out.println("   TestScenario ExecNo :" + tc.getTestScenarioExecNo());
            System.out.println("      TestCase ExecNo :" + tc.getTestCaseExecNo());
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
    }


    return root1;
}
```

If i want to loop root1 object and print data in console, How to do ?
Actually, I want to loop through root1 and get the data from tree and wanted to store in db. But i am not getting and idea how to loop root1 object and get data printed on console.

Could anyone help me on this ?

Thanks
Neeraj

Comment: Did you consult the [API documentation for DefaultTreeNode](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/6.0/org/primefaces/model/DefaultTreeNode.html)? There is `getChildren()` to loop over and `getData()` to retrieve the content. This is for PrimeFaces v6.0. Please provide version information next time.

Comment: what i used to help to make something like that fast and easy is to make a list of sons in the entity and i fill the `SonsList` every time i need it ( it is generally one time )

Comment: Hi Irieill, Thanks for your reply. Here is my code where i am able to get treedata `List<TreeNode> ParentNode = root1.getChildren();
  for(TreeNode P : ParentNode)
  {  
   TestProcess x1 = (TestProcess)P.getData();      
 Syso(x1.getTestScenarioName());     
     List<TreeNode> childNode = P.getChildren();
     for(TreeNode c: childNode)
     {
             TestProcess x = (TestProcess)c.getData();
       
      System.out.println("Child Data : "+ x.getTestScenarioName());
      
     }
    }`